# Creating custom slots and signals old style

Tags: pyqt4

I'm trying to create my own custom signal but for whatever reason it's not going into the function.  Any ideas where I went wrong?

```py
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.connect( self, QtCore.SIGNAL( 'dagEvent(type, *args)' ), self.OnDagEvent)

def someFunc(self, ...):
    ...
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent()'), type, *args)

def OnDagEvent( self, eventType, eventData ):
    print 'Test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are creating the signature for you custom signal. There are a few ways you are allow to do it, but the way you have it now isn't one of them.

When you define your connection, the way you are doing it should be causing an error to be raised:

```
# not a valid type of signature
QtCore.SIGNAL( 'dagEvent(type, *args)' )
```

And even if that were allowed to be created, when you emit later, you are not referencing the same signature anyways:

```
# if it were even allowed, would have to be: dagEvent(type, *args)
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent()'), type, *args)
```

---

#### [Old-style Signal and Slot Support](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/old_style_signals_slots.html)

The easiest way to create a custom signal from PyQt is to simply use the callable name only:

```py
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent'), self.OnDagEvent)
...
# "type" is a builtin. I renamed it to type_
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent'), type_, *args)
```

This approach does not care what args you decide to pass it. You can pass anything you want.

If you want to specifically control the signature, you can define builtin types:

```py
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent(int,str,int)'), self.OnDagEvent)
...
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent(int,str,int)'), i1, s2, i3)
```

If you fail to use the right signature in the emit, it will not be called, and passing the wrong types when emitting will raise an error.

Now if you want to somewhat define a signature, but not limit it to any basic type, and allow any python object, you can do this:

```py
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent(PyQt_PyObject)'), self.OnDagEvent)
...
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dagEvent(PyQt_PyObject)'), foo)
```

This will allow any single python object to be passed, but specifically says it expects 1 argument.